# How to get the days difference of two xs.date in MarkLogic?

Tags: javascript, datetime, marklogic

What is the appropriate function for getting the days (numeric) difference between two `xs.date` type?

```
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();

date1 = xs.date("2018-03-29");
date2 = xs.date("2018-04-15");
```

I tried using **`fn.daysFromDuration`** function (see sample below), but it is not returning a numeric value which represents the days difference. It is returning a `xs.dayTimeDuration`:

```
var dateDiff = new Date();
dateDiff = fn.daysFromDuration(date2 - date1);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `date2 - date1` to calculate the difference between dates and yield a `xs.dayTimeDuration` in JavaScript, like you can in XQuery.

In an SJS module, use the [`xs.date.subtract()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xs.date.subtract) from the `xs.date` object, then you can use [`fn.daysFromDuration()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.daysFromDuration) to obtain the number of days as a number:

```
const date1 = xs.date("2018-03-29");
const date2 = xs.date("2018-04-15");

fn.daysFromDuration(date2.subtract(date1));
```

Comment: Note that fn.daysFromDuration does not convert months or years to days. Luckily xs.date.subtract only returns durations with a days component.